# How to fetch screen recordings video

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, photokit

As we know, we can fetch screenshot photos with `PhotoKit` framework like this,

```
 let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumScreenshots, options: fetchOption)
```

But how to fetch screen recordings videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let res = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset).first {
       if res.originalFilename.hasPrefix("RPReplay") {              
          screenRecordings.append(asset.localIdentifier)
       } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this ⬇️

```
func openVideoGallery() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .savedPhotosAlbum)!
    picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]      
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now Implement delegate methods to retrieve selected video.